# How to use the OneVsRestClassifier in Scikit-learn to analyse the performance of predicting each individual class with multi-class classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In the OneVsRestClassifier documentation on the scikit-learn website it states the following:

"Since each class is represented by one and one classifier only, it is possible to gain knowledge about the class by inspecting its corresponding classifier."

But it gives no explanation of how to do this and I can't see how any of the methods in the documentation on this page could achieve that. I want to be able to print out the accuracy of the model for each individual class, so that I can see the performance it has at predicting each class.

The code I have so far is below, but I really don't know where to go from here, as it seems that there is nothing in the documentation, which explains how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def predict_one_vs_rest(self):
    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
    clf.fit(self.X, self.y)
    result = clf.classes_
    estimators = clf.estimators_
    print(result)
    print("")
    print(estimators)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap LinearSVC in OneVsRestClassifier. As the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/multiclass.html) clearly says, LinearSVC already supports multi-class classification.
For inspecting accuracy of the classes, you could use the confusion matrix or the classification report, for example.

Comment: Thanks for that, I ended up using the classification report.

Comment: @Andreas Mueller I am wondering what if it is the classifier that doesn't support multi-class or multi-label classification I want to use? It seems that OneVsRestClassifier is needed in such case, and how can I evaluate the performance of each individual class as asked in OP?

Comment: All classifiers in sklearn support multi-class. For multi-label, you can indeed use OVR if the estimator doesn't support it.
Using OVR or not doesn't make any difference for evaluation, though.
You can check in the docs which metrics support multi-label tasks.

Comment: @AndreasMueller: I'm using linear regression classifier for multi class. It gives 50 percent total accuracy. When I want to plot ROC curves, I need to use OVR with linear regression, which gives the score 27 percent. But the ROC curves are as good as the confusion matrix and the area is nearly 0.8 for all classes. what is the reason for the poor accuracy.

Comment: linear regression is not a classifier

Comment: Do I gain a parallelization benefit  by explicitly wrapping a SVC (which does not have a n_jobs parameter) in a OneVsRestClassifier (which can tell how many threads i want it to use)?

Comment: @bmurauer Yes, that would allow you to use multiple cores. In general that doesn't necessarily mean it's faster, but I think the OvO in SVC is completely serial and there is no common computations, so I think it should be faster. (Be aware that SVC uses OvO not OvR internally).